# Infinite recursion when deserializing with Jackson and Mockito

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, mockito, jackson-databind

I am trying to generically print any object with `mapper.writeValueAsString` but I am facing a infinite recursion when deserializing objects with Mockito and Jackson. The objects I am trying to deserialize perform underlying Hibernate calls to DBs etc and I have no control over the classes themselves.

Currently I am using the following versions of Mockito and Jackson but the same is happening for older 1.X versions of Jackson.

- Mockito: `org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:compile`
- Jackson: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7:compile`

As specified, I cannot modify the underlying classes with annotation such as `@JsonIgnore` because they are outside dependencies not under my control. I also cannot create mixins for my user case because I am trying to generically print the contents of any object that is sent in.

I have tried adding the `DeserializationConfig FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to `false` in older Jackson version and I have tried setting the `DeserializationFeature FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES` to `false`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public static PrintUtil {
    public static String printJSON(Object obj) {
        String printstring = "printfailed";
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            LOG.debug("formatted JSON String ");
            printstring = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return printstring;
    }
}
```

The infinite recursion terminal output is seen when running Mockito tests for methods that contain Log4j statements which in turn call the PrintUtil function. The statement `e.printStackTrace()` begins printing while running the tests.

Most of the object that are being sent to this utility method are JAXB XML Service Response Objects.

Comment: I cannot see what is the role of mockito here? Also, what is the object that you are trying to serialize?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I have edited my question and added more information regarding mockito and the objects I am serializing.

Comment: You might want to look at `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonIgnoreProperties` or the `@JsonManagedReference / @JsonBackReference` combination to see which best fits your use case.

Comment: @TheHeadRush As I stated in the question I cannot add annotations to the objects I am passing in because they are not owned by me and they are mostly JAXB XML objects which are essentially Interfaces for underlying C++ objects.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to modify the classes themselves, I see two possible solutions.

1) Wrap the objects into objects you own as suggested by [@TheHeadRush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3812888/the-head-rush) and annotate it appropriately. I would suggest using `@JsonIdentityInfo` so the objects serialize to their ID, rather than being ignored completely with `@JsonIgnore`.

2) Use a custom deserializer for the object which is causing the recursion. Here is an example:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyObject>{

   // Add constructors as necessary.

    @Override
    public List<Item> deserialize(
      JsonParser jsonparser, 
      DeserializationContext context) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
       return null; // Return something that won't recurse here.
    }
}
```

Then register the deserializer with the `ObjectMapper` you are using:

```
// Register the deserializer:
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
    .addDeserializer(MyObject.class, new CustomDeserializer());

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```